# vim linux column formatting -- handling string literals

Tags: linux, vim, multiple-columns

Doing some programming in VIM I'd like to automatically line some stuff up in columns. Doing :!column -t works for the most part but it doesn't know the concept of a string literal so those are getting modified as well. Is there any short way of getting it to treat the string literal as a single cell of the column?

*** edit ***

For example, if I currently have the rows

```
stringType short "Short string" plusSome
otherStringType longStringName "Intentionally do a longer string" plusSomeMore
```

I'd like it to be formatted as

```
stringType      short          "Short string"                     plusSome
otherStringType longStringName "Intentionally do a longer string" plusSomeMore
```

instead of

```
stringType      short          "Short         string" plusSome
otherStringType longStringName "Intentionally do      a        longer string" plusSomeMore
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular) plugin, it does what you want and a lot more.  See [this screencast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/aligning-text-with-tabular-vim/) for a quick intro.

Comment: I looked at that but I still don't see how to make it treat a string literal as a single element

Comment: @ryan0270 I'm not sure I understand.  With tabular you're supposed to describe (with a regexp) the _separator_ between columns.  What string literals do you want to handle, and what do you mean by treating them as single elements?

Comment: I've added an example